# How do I dynamically assign the ImageUrl property of an image, using data binding?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I've got a SQL Server database with a table in it, which lists the file names of images.  It's my intention to assign the ImageUrl of an Image control on the page, from the data in the table.  I've placed a SQLDataSource control on the page, and then tried putting a FormView control there, and an Image control within that.  But I don't see how I can assign the value to the ImageUrl property *via* data binding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

inside whatever type of control your using to return the data you would do something like...

```
<asp:imagebutton id="btnId" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImgUrl") %>' />
```

Play with that and give it a try... most of what i do is in datagridviews or repeaters... but that doesnt really matter much its the bind or eval that matters.

A bit more information for you Rod.

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataReader"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT LastName FROM Employees">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource2"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataReader"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName FROM Employees">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>


  <asp:ListBox
      id="ListBox1"
      runat="server"
      DataTextField="LastName"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  </asp:ListBox>
  <asp:ListBox
      id="ListBox2"
      runat="server"
      DataTextField="FirstName"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
  </asp:ListBox>
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Instead of Bind you should use Eval if it's only for display

Comment: i tend to agree... not knowing exactly what he is planning for it ultimately so i figgured id start with the bind.

Comment: This looks like it will work, but I've got a follow-up question.  I've got 2 SqlDataSource controls on the page.  How will the Bind() method know which one to use?

Comment: @Rod.  In the control that you are binding you will have a DataSourceID...  If you have multiple data sources each one needs to have a different id.  the control then knows which data source to bind from based on the datasource id

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way of doing this sort of binding, well cleaner to me at least, would be to handle the binding in the ItemDataBound event.

So you would do something like:

```
Image imageToBind = e.Item.FindControl("imgTest") as Image;
image.ImageUrl = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "ColumnName");
```

I just find that to be more elegant than doing it in the actual markup.

Comment: I don't think is cleaner to add and EventHandler and add two lines of code which treats ids of controls as strings and uses cast in codebehind when a single attribute in the markup is enough. This solution: Imperative. Patrick's  solution: More declarative

Comment: Subjective then I guess.  Whenever I see a repeater with Eval/Bind all over the place it just irks me.  I think handling it within the code behind is just cleaner and easier to view/understand.

Answer (score 1):

.aspx.cs

```
public string GetImage(string status)
    {
        if (status=="Active")

            return "~/images/green_acti.png";

        else

            return "~/images/red_acti.png";

    }
```

.aspx

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="|| Status ||">
          <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgGreenAct" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "truck_status")))%>' AlternateText='<%# Bind("truck_status") %>' runat="server" />                            
          </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```